# How can I add an unknown class with HostBinding?

Tags: angular, angular2-hostbinding

I want to use `HostBinding` decorator in order to add a class, which cannot be hardcoded like `@HostBinding('class.myClass')`.

I know there is a possibility to bind it to the whole `class` attribute like `@HostBinding('class')`, but that will obviously reset all classes added directly to my host element in the place where it is used.

So is it possible to use `HostBinding`, but only to add one class and preserve all previously added classes in html?

Currently I ended up with uglier solution:

```
@Component({
    ...
})
class MyComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private hostElement: ElementRef,
                private renderer: Renderer2) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        const randomClass = `dynamic-${Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1}`;
        this.renderer.addClass(this.hostElement.nativeElement, dynamicClass);
    }
}
```

Comment: this @HostBinding('class.my-class') myclass = true;  add my-class to :host element

Comment: Yes, but as I said, I don't know in advance the class name I wan't to add. That's why I use Math.random in the example. Therefore I cannot use hardcoded `class.my-class`

Comment: I can see the point even if I don't understand how to style the element without knowing the class  - btw I think your way is the way to go

Comment: Hehe, yes absolutely valid point. :D
In real world scenario this class actually isn't totally dynamic. Someone is writing a styles for it, we just don't know it in that given time in code.
Thanks @Whisher

Comment: https://alligator.io/angular/using-renderer2/ you can also use a directive you could add the class dynamically using @Input

Comment: Well that's a valid option as well. I will see which one will make more sense with time. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Overriding the native `class=""` attribute with an `@Input() class: string;` looks promising. I haven't tested this very thoroughly, but it seems to work so far.

```js
import { Component, Input, HostBinding } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'gist-keeps-class',
    template: 'this component keeps class="class" attributes'
})
export class KeepsClass {

    @Input() booleanInput: boolean = false;
    @Input() stringInput: 'some-thing' | 'another-thing' | 'a-third-thing' = 'another-thing';

    @Input() class: string = ''; // override the standard class attr with a new one.
    @HostBinding('class')
    get hostClasses(): string {
        return [
            this.class, // include our new one 
            this.booleanInput ? 'has-boolean' : '',
            this.stringInput
        ].join(' ');
    }

}
```

template with this:

```html
<gist-keeps-class 
  class="some classes" 
  [booleanInput]="true" 
  [stringInput]="some-thing"
></gist-keeps-class>
```

will output this:

```html
  <gist-keeps-class class="some classes has-boolean some-thing" >
    this component keeps class="class" attributes
  </gist-keeps-class>
```

[gist](https://gist.github.com/arniebradfo/912fc4893d5bf3a38ba63b5f60f7443d)

Comment: perfect answer has been looking for

Comment: If you have complex classes to 'finagle' together you may want to consider https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames